# Unity3d and Parse: Query failing on Relation after updating Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

When Querying a relation, we started getting this error.

ArgumentNullException: Must specify a ParseObject class name when creating a ParseQuery.

1. It only happens on iOS, and not in the Unity editor.
2. Started happening on Parse 1.6.1

We are querying a relation in this manner:

```
var FBFriendsRelation = ParseUser.CurrentUser.GetRelation<ParseUser> ("FBFriends");
        if (FBFriendsRelation != null) {
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> q = FBFriendsRelation.Query;
```

In Xcode, the error happens on the final line, the actual query. We are doing this as described in the docs, and since it works in the API tool and Unity editor, seems to be a valid query.

Are we just running into a bug with Parse?  If anyone knows a workaround, would appreciate it. At this point we just may avoid the relation and query it outright.